# Opening network shares takes some time at home lan

Tags: networking

At home I set up a LAN with DHCP, but with static leases for the PCs. At work there is a network with static IP, additionally the PCs are in the hosts file.

When I access the PCs from each other at home, it takes some seconds till the shares come up. The same with administrative shares, it takes some time to open, afterwards it is fast.

Everything is connected via cable.

At work this opens immediately. What is the difference? How can I make my home PCs open as quickly as the work PCs?

Comment: Are the PCs in question being moved between your work and home? Are they part of a domain network?

Comment: The PCs stay where they are. They are not part of a domain, the work PCs are mixed, a large part is not domain intentionally. The home PCs are in a homegroup.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

According to **Microsoft** link:[Slow network performance when you open a file that is located in a shared folder on a remote network computer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/829700/slow-network-performance-when-you-open-a-file-that-is-located-in-a-sha)

It could be that you windows want to get the detailed information about the sharing folder and the sharing file you want to open.

Try the following several registries, please remember ti backup the registry before you modify.
Run the `regedit` as administrator.

1.path:`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\CryptoSignMenu`
name:`SuppressionPolicy`
type:`Dword(32-bit)`
value: `Hexadecimal` `100000`

2.path:`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\{3EA48300-8CF6-101B-84FB-666CCB9BCD32}`
name:`SuppressionPolicy`
type:`Dword(32-bit)`
value: `Hexadecimal` `100000`

3.path:`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\{883373C3-BF89-11D1-BE35-080036B11A03}`
name:`SuppressionPolicy`
type:`Dword(32-bit)`
value: `Hexadecimal` `100000`

4.path:`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SCAPI`
name:`Flags`
type:`Dword(32-bit)`
value: `Hexadecimal` `00100c02`

Then enable the group policy setting.
(1) run `gpedit`
(2) Find `User Configuration-> Administrative Templates-> Windows Components->Windows Explorer`
(3) You can see `Allow only per user or approved shell extensions`, enable it

Hope above information can help you.